# efficiency of grouping the results of a grouping query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

given a table that represents objects that belong to users and that has 2 colomns: `oid` and `uid`

I want to know how many users have how many objects...
i.e.
10 users have 3 objects
20 users have 2 objects
40 users have 1 object

I guess I could first count objects per user:

```
select uid,count(oid) c from t group by uid
```

and then revers the grouping:

```
select c,count(uid) from 
   ( select uid,count(oid) c from t group by uid ) g
group by c
```

Is there a way to do this type of query in a more efficient way?

Comment: in first query you are getting the objects per user,why you want to reverse grouping.? what is your purpose behind it.?

Comment: As I wrote "I want to know how many users have how many objects... i.e. 10 users have 3 objects 20 users have 2 objects 40 users have 1 object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to accomplish this in standard SQL. If you have a procedural language at your disposal, you could write a function to do it, but I think your subquery approach is straightforward and efficient enough.